# Is it possible to represent the +X symbolic permission with an octal value?

Tags: permissions, chmod

Is it possible to represent the +X symbolic permission with an octal value? The chmod(1) man page says:

> execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user

which means that `chmod -R g+X` will add the group execute permission only if there's already an execute bit set for user, group, or other. You could certainly do this the hard way with find:

```
find . -perm /ugo=x -exec chmod g+x {} \;
```

However, it's not obvious how one could do the same thing with an octal mode without using *find* or *test* to check the file permissions first. Is this possible, or are there some areas where symbolic and octal permissions just don't overlap?

Comment: [GNU coreutils: Conditional Executability](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Conditional-Executability.html#Conditional-Executability)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short story: it's not possible, no.

The longer story: octal permissions are states. The `[+-][rwxXst]` notation represents `operations` that culminate in changing states. Note, not the `=[rwxXst]` one, which *sets* state and is equivalent to the octal modes as Gilles said. The `X` one is the only conditional operation, the other ones are all unconditional.

When you `chmod` a file with octal permissions, you supply the final *state* of the permission bits verbatim. When you use the operations, you choose what you want *done* to the permission bits.

Your question is tantamount to asking if there's a single number that represents all square roots. The answers is obviously ‘no’: every square root *yields* a number (pedants: though it could be imaginary/irrational), but without the starting *state* (the number), you can't tell which.

Comment: Both you and @Gilles did a great job of answering the question. Even though GNU chmod supports a number of [operator numeric modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Operator-Numeric-Modes.html#Operator-Numeric-Modes), I thought your explanation of the difference between setting state and performing operations was a useful abstraction. Thank you both.

Comment: Thanks! The operator numeric modes are what `[rwxst]` are internally translated to. E.g. `x=1, r=2, w=4` shifted appropriately, then used to set or clear bits in the `st_mode` field. But `X` is implemented like `if (f.st_mode & 0111) ...`, so it's again special. It's not evident from the manual, but there's still no way you can do `X` with operator numeric modes.

Comment: your 'x' in `The x one is the only` should be uppercase, yes?

Comment: It should be! I checked, and it is. I think it's the relative size of the monospace font to the sans-serif one: Xx`Xx`. Which of course doesn't work in the comments because they use a smaller size. :)

Answer (score 4):

Symbolic modes are more expressive than octal modes, because octal modes can only express absolute changes. Relative changes, which means not only `+X` but any mode that doesn't specify all the new bits (such as `g+x` — or even `a+rwx`, which doesn't remove any setuid/setgid bit), cannot be expressed with octal modes.

Conversely, any octal mode can be expressed as a symbolic mode, in general by using `=`, e.g. `4750` = `u+rwxs,g=rx,o-rwxt` (or `u=rwxs,g=rx,o=` or many other combinations).