# How can I give a permssion to all users for a path using the octal notation?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I'd like to give execute permissions on a path recursively so I can read a file in the directory. The `chmod` binary that I'm using on Android only supports the octal/numeric notation though.

Normally I'd do `chmod -R a+x /this/file/is/here/filename.txt` but don't know how I'd do this numerically. I've Googled but haven't found an answer to this.

---

Looking at at the question "[Is it possible to represent the +X symbolic permission with an octal value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41623/)", I don't think this is possible but what would the easiest recommended way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that using octal notation. Octal notation only allows you to set all mode bits and the `+x` allows to *add* to existing mode bits.

If you have `find` on the system, you can write a script that uses find to search for directories a specific combination of mode bits with `-perm` and change only those to the pattern including the execute bits.

@Wally's solution will not work because directories A and B:

```
-rwxrwxr-- A
-rwxr-xr-- B
```

will both become `rwxr-xr-x` with his solutions but with `chmod a+x`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x A
-rwxr-xr-x B
```

Answer (score 0):

Permissions with chmod are as follows:

```
User (r-w-e)
User's primary group (r-w-e)
Everyone (r-w-e)
```

You probably want to give permissions as follows:

```
chmod 755
```

Which gives User: rwe, Group: re, Everyone: re

It's usually helpful to have the *read-execute* together, rather than just *execute*.